# TinyMCE 4 - Plain text/strip HTML tags button

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

Is there a way to completely strip the selected elements of their styles AND HTML tags?

So `<p>Text</p>` would become `Text`.

Either using a custom button (function), or a 'Plain Text' style in the formats dropdown?

Comment: There is a PHP function for that, if you are keen.

Comment: How does that work? I'd definitely prefer a pure JavaScript solution but that could be an option.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Anub for direction, I managed to do this myself.

```
// Store the current selections string/value in a variable and strip it's tags
var node = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent({ format : 'text' });

// Replace the selected content with the stripped out content
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent(node);
```

Answer (score 4):

try

selection.getContent({format : 'text'});

or

selection.getContent({format : 'html'});

Comment: This just get's the selected content but I need to way to set it to be able to remove the tags

Comment: var node = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', false, %your value, can use node%");

Comment: Getting close, now my h2 and h3 tags are being combined into a h2 tag (the text inside is combined). Anyway to remove the h2 tag also? Thanks